# Is there a way to store Firefox passwords in a local encrypted database in Linux?

Tags: security, password, firefox, browser, kwallet

I want Firefox to "remember" my passwords so I don't have to type them in; unfortunately, the built-in password manager stores them in plain text, which is too high a security risk. I'd like to find a secure way for Firefox to do basically the same thing. Though I've heard good things about LastPass and other such services, I'm not too comfortable entrusting them with my data; any of those companies could suddenly change their terms, start charging, or just go under. I love the idea of [KeeFox](http://keefox.org), but alas, it's not available for Linux. Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think Firefox is storing them plain text?  Isn't there a master password to protect the password db?

Comment: is browser integration a requirement? or do you just want storage? also what desktop environment?

Comment: Readers of this question may also be interested in [How are browser saved passwords vulnerable?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3694/414).

Comment: And also, independently of the way the passwords are stored, they are also very insecure because they may be viewed directly going to: `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Security` -> `Passwords` -> `Show passwords`. That option is with Firefox 3.x and also with Firefox 4.

Comment: @nozimica You need to re-enter the master password to actually see the passwords if you go to `Show passwords` - of course, you need to set first the master password.

Answer (score 9):

You can encrypt and protect your Firefox passwords with a master password:

> Preferences → Security → Passwords

Then check:

> ☑ Use a master password

Then set a master password.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are mistaken. When using the Password manager, [Firefox does not store your passwords in clear text](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_Manager):

> Firefox stores your password data in
>   two files: key3.db (Master Password /
>   Encryption key) and a "signons" file
>   (encrypted names and passwords). You
>   can back up your passwords by making a
>   copy of both "Key3.db" and the
>   "signons" file for your Firefox
>   version. Firefox 2 uses signons2.txt,
>   Firefox 3.0.x uses signons3.txt, and
>   Firefox 3.5 and 3.6, including current
>   Beta and nightly builds, use
>   signons.sqlite. [4] See Profile folder
>   - Firefox and Profile backup for additional information.

If you are concerned, you could enable encryption of your entire home directory as an added protection.

Answer (score 7):

Depending what Desktop Environment you're using you could integrate Firefox with default password storage mechanism for this environment:

- KDE - KWallet
- GNOME - GNOMEKeyring

If you want integrate Firefox with KWallet you could use [KDE Wallet password integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/49357/) extension for Firefox. If you are GNOME user there is [Gnome-keyring password integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8737/) extension (you need to modify it to install with newest Firefox version - instructions are in comments at the extension site).

Comment: Ooooh, great tip!

Comment: by any chance does that kwallet extension exist for chrome do you know?

Comment: I'm not even sure if it is possible - as I know Chrome API for extensions is less advanced that Firefox API...

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable FIPS Mode.

Enable it by:
    Preferences->Advanced->Encryption->Security Devices->Enable FIPS

You must have a Master Password set on your password database for this to work, but these are the settings we put in place here at the security company where I work. If we store passwords in the browser, then these two steps must be taken in order for it to be acceptable security-wise to the company.

For an explanation on FIPS 140-2, and why you'd want to do this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NSS/FIPS_Mode_-_an_explanation

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why keefox isn't running in linux, i havent looked at it yet.
I'm securing my important files with encfs and fuse, because it doesn't need a block or loop device and encrypts file by file. 
http://www.arg0.net/encfs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if such a hackery method is the best approach, but I think in case we see any other program show such a behavior, this will be a good idea to create a link to a named pipe (in case you use Unix-like) with the same name as the file and encrypt the other head of pipe. So each time a write is done it'll be encrypted and decrypted when reading.

I think it could be handy at times, and I should say I haven't tested it yet (popped up into my mind suddenly).

Answer (score 0):

Now there is [addon KeeFox for Firefox for Linux](http://keefox.org/2012/03/14/keefox-095-and-linuxmac-support/#comment-505545908).

Need to install all the mono packages:

```
aptitude install mono-complete
```

You need to download latest compatible with linux [Version of KeePass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keefox/versions/) FireFox Addon.

You will need to install [PassiFox](https://github.com/pfn/passifox) for FireFox and [KeePassHttp](https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp) for KeePass in order to connect KeeFox and KeePass (That is strange but it is working).

Configure KeeFox with directory to the KeePassRPC plugin.

```
/usr/lib/keepass2/plugins
```

and KeePass2 installation dir

```
/usr/bin
```